# How to create auto dialer in iPhone using MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, phone-call, core-telephony

I need to create button to call one contact number, that number is the default number and I will mention that number in button click event.

When I click on button need to dial that number in iPhone using MonoTouch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(NSUrl.FromString("tel://1234567890"));
```

Comment: In the sense we can not make call from Simulator..Isn't it?

Comment: No, the simulator is not capable of making phone calls.

Comment: Ok,Thank you..will it work in device only? and can i test it in device only?

Comment: just make sure you only pass numbers after tel:// (no spaces, parentheses, etc)