# MonoTouch : Can I use a UILabel to show a phone number?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, uilabel, phone-call

I need to show a phone number in a view and that when clicked a call is initiated. Currently I'm using an `UILabel` and I have no idea how to do it.

Is this the correct control? If no which one would be?

If it's the correct one, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `UILabel` could be used (kind of showing a link) but an `UIButton` might be more appropriate.

You can find the code to initiate the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8080810/220643) (and answer).

Using a `UIButton` and the code from above would give you:

```
var btn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
btn.Frame = new RectangleF (10,10,100,200);
btn.SetTitle ("call me", UIControlState.Normal); 
btn.TouchUpInside += delegate {
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (NSUrl.FromString ("tel://411"));
};
```

Comment: The "911" is a brilliant number for testing purposes! :-)

Comment: I prefer it to look like a link, like what you get when you send a SMS with a phone number, is there any other control outside UILabel that I can use?

Comment: Not sure I understand *outside UILabel* ? If you want something else then the example above use a UIButton, which you can customize (not to look so like a button).

Comment: I got a solution, The best way is simply no using an UILabel but an UIButton with the "custom" mode (the first dropdown in the inspector @ interface builder)